# MSNodeSQL query error results or misunderstanding of JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, sql-server, json, node.js

I'm confused by the callback arguments when an MSNodeSQL query fails.  I'm new to JavaScript so this may be a simple JavaScript problem. The simplified query to the database is:

```
conn.query(storedProc, params, function( err, result ) {
if (err) {
        console.log("err = " + err);
        console.log("err = " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

I renamed a stored procedure so it would not be found and an error would be forced. The err argument shows a meaningful description of the error as:

```
err = Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.me3_MsgQueueIn_AddMessage'.
```

When I send this variable back to the client and show it in a browser it appears as a JSON object and I see now when I display it at the server as shown above, it is a JSON object and I see

```
err = {"sqlstate":"42000","code":2812}
```

While it is nice to have a specific error code like this, it is also nice to have a meaningful description of the error.

Can anyone explain how err can apparently have two values, a string and a JSON object?

Secondly how can I see the meaningful description in the browser at the client because currently I only see the JSON object with its two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is a customized Error used by the mysql package. The Error object is not exactly a JSON object like others. **What is contained in the Error isn't what is shown in `JSON.stringify`**

Take this code as an example:

```
function CustomError( msg ){
  var err = Error.call( this, msg );
  err.customField = "abc";
  return err;
}

var err = new Error("Bad thing");
console.log("err = " + err);   
console.log("err = " + JSON.stringify(err));

var customErr = new CustomError("Custom Bad thing");
console.log("customErr = " + customErr );
console.log("customErr = " + JSON.stringify(customErr) );
```

Which gives output like this:

```
err = Error: Bad thing
err = {}
customErr = Error: Custom Bad thing
customErr = {"customField":"abc"}
```

As you can see, the customized error is only showing the fields that are defined for it, which is the JSON object you see returned to your client.

There are fun properties of Errors too!

`name` is the type of error. Try adding `err.name = "CustomError";` to the custom error definition. It will change the output to "customErr = **CustomError**: Custom Bad thing" (emphasis mine).

Want to see that error message on your client? Try `err.message`, which is everything after the name. That is the string used on Error creation.

A fun one is the `stack` property, which prints out the stack trace of the Error. Don't send that to your client : ) It's also what you'll see if an Error is thrown, and not caught. Give `throw customErr;` a try (though note that will stop the Node process).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for the detailed explanation from which I've learned a alot.